# Difference in files laravel install local & on server

Tags: laravel, composer-php, centos7

When I install laravel on the server via the command:

```
cd httpdocs/ && /opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

I am missing files and folders in the laravel directory, which I would have when I install laravel local on my laptop with the command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

The commands are the same, but why am I missing files on the server? Example of a missing file: /app/Http/routes.php and missing folder: /app/events/

In both situations laravel works and shows the default laravel page when I visit the url.

Hope to get a clear answer, I couldn't find it on google or here on stackoverflow.

Comment: routes.php was removed in Laravel 5.4 I believe.  Everything is in a routes directory now.   What version is installed on both?  Check your composer.json file.

Comment: You are right, the versions differ.
How come it installs another version on local then on server? Used the same commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested this.  When using `composer create-project`, it looks like it will use the maximum version it can while satisfying project requirements.

Therefore, if you're installing using PHP 7.1, it will be able to install the latest, Laravel 5.6.  However, if you're running create-project using PHP 5.6, it will only attempt to install Laravel 5.4 since Laravel 5.5 requires PHP 7.0 and 5.6 requires 7.1.

This leads me to believe you don't have a recent version of PHP set up on your local system.